# Generate random vector which is perpendicular to a set of given vectors

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a set of vectors which are pairwise perpendicular. Then I would like to generate a new vector which should be perpendicular to all the vectors in the given set and it should be chosen at random. Basically, if `d` is the dimensionality of the problem and `m` is the number of given vectors, then the set of vectors that are perpendicular to those spans a `(d-m)`-dimensional subspace. I would like to randomly sample a vector from this subspace.

I can use [`np.linalg.lstsq`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) in order to find a vector that is perpendicular to all the others, but the result won't be random:

```py
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)

d = 8  # number of dimensions

vectors = [rng.normal(size=d)]
for _ in range(d-1):
    vectors.append(np.linalg.lstsq(
        np.stack(vectors, axis=0),
        np.zeros(len(vectors)),
        rcond=None,
    )[0])


import itertools as it

for i, j in it.combinations(range(d), r=2):
    assert abs(vectors[i] @ vectors[j]) < 1e-16
```

So I think I should be sampling `(d-m)` components at random and then determine the others with [`np.linalg.solve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html). For example:

```py
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)

d = 10  # number of dimensions

vectors = [rng.normal(size=d)]
for _ in range(d-1):
    random_indices = rng.choice(np.arange(d), size=d-len(vectors), replace=False)
    random_mask = np.zeros(d, dtype=bool)
    random_mask[random_indices] = True

    random_components = rng.normal(size=random_mask.sum())

    matrix = np.stack(vectors, axis=0)
    other_components = np.linalg.solve(
        matrix[:, ~random_mask],
        -(matrix[:, random_mask] @ random_components),
    )
    new = np.empty_like(vectors[-1])
    new[random_mask] = random_components
    new[~random_mask] = other_components

    for v in vectors:
        assert abs(v @ new) < 1e-12, f'dot product: {v @ new}'
    vectors.append(new)
```

For the above to work, however, I have to relax the perpendicularity condition `v @ new == 0` depending on the number of dimensions. For example for `d = 10` I can only require `v @ new < 1e-12` while for `d = 20` the threshold is `1e-10`. For the least squares solution, it was sufficient to use the same threshold independent of `d` (in fact, all dot products were zero).

Also, I'm not absolutely certain if the above algorithm, i.e. first randomly sampling the indices of to-be-randomized components, then determining the others, will yield a truly random vector out of this subspace. How could I verify this?

Comment: Did you notice that in your first code block, all the vectors in `vectors` except the first are all zero?

Comment: You could generate a random d-dimensional vector, and then subtract from it its projection onto the given m vectors.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Good idea. When I checked it, the required threshold still increased with the number of dimensions but it was orders of magnitude smaller than the other method. For my application these small deviations don't matter anyway. And I guess I can convince myself that if the algorithm starts from a random vector in the entire d-dimensional space, the resulting perpendicular vector will be random as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this iteratively using the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process)

```py
n = 100;
d = 20;
v = np.random.rand(n);
v = v / np.sqrt(np.sum(np.abs(v)**2));
V = [v]

for i in range(d):
    v = np.random.rand(n);
    # orthogonalize
    v = v - sum(vi * np.sum(vi.conj() * v) for vi in V);
    # normalize
    v = v / np.sqrt(np.sum(np.abs(v)**2))
    V.append(v);
A = np.array(V)
np.allclose(A @ A.T, np.eye(d+1)) # check the result
```

In this example I started with an empty basis.

If you already have the basis and want a single vector you simply repeat what I did in the last iteration.

Comment: You can use [`v /= np.linalg.norm(v)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) to normalize the vectors. And `vi @ v` allows to compute the dot product.

Comment: Of course, this is only a reference implementation. You could also make V a numpy array and vectorize the projection with something like `v - V[:i].T @ (V[:i] @ v)`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I was more concerned with readability. Vectorizing the whole thing doesn't necessarily make it more readable, but usage of `norm` and `@` does in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you, at least I got the question correctly :)-